# Google Sheets - Data validation from a horizontal range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do something which seems straight forward enough. In the cell (`D15`) validation rules, I want to choose, `List from a range` and specify a range that is horizontal, instead of vertical. Please see the following self-explanatory screenshot.

[image: Horizontal Data Range]

However, this doesn't work. The drop-down only shows data from the first column of the given range. See the screenshot below.

[image: Data from first column of range]

How can I make this work? I expect to see - Cat, Mouse, Lion, and Deer in the drop down list.

PS: Arranging the items I want in the list, vertically, is not an option.

**SOLUTION**
Similar in principle to the accepted answer by @Marios, I found a solution for my exact use case [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6735222?msgid=6773038). Unfortunately, AppScript seems to be the only answer.

Comment: Seems to work fine here. Try clearing your cache. Closing and Opening

Comment: @TheMaster Really? You're seeing all the items in the dropdown specified using the horizontal range?

Comment: @TheMaster I think you might have specified a closed range e.g. `E15:H15`. I see that it works for closed ranges, but not for open ranges like `E15:15`.

Comment: Yeah. Figured it out. It is a bug than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternative Solution:

How about the following [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) solution.

The following code will create a data validation in cell **D15** and the data validation values are given by the range **E15:H15**:

```
function setDataValidation() {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = sh.getRange('D15'); // data validation cell
var range = sh.getRange('E15:H15'); // range of options
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

---

### Instructions:

1. Click on **Tools** => **Script editor**:

[image: step1]

2. **Copy and Paste** the aforementioned code snippet into the script editor and click run (play button):

[image: step2]

---

### Further ideas:

- Instead of executing the function from the script editor, you can
  create a button in the google sheets UI to execute this function for you.
- Another approach would be for the user to select the range of the list he wants as values for the data validation cell and then click the button to automatically create a data validation cell for him.
- You can also create a trigger to create a data validation cell when something is edited.
- Instead of creating a data validation only for one cell, you can do it for a range of cells etc.

---

### References:

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Class DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)
- [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Ouch! I was hoping the answer would not involve AppScript. I really wonder why a seemingly simple thing, isn't possible.

Comment: I'll give it to you if I don't get a direct (non AppScript) solution.

Comment: @CodePoet I hope you will find what you need. I just added an approach as a plan B :)

Comment: *The general rule of thumb: If it can't be done  manually through UI, It can't be done through apps script.* Here you show it works through apps script. Then the reverse must hold: It can be done through the UI as well. cc @CodePoet

Comment: @TheMaster the OP wants to select the full row and not a specific row range as Oleg proposed. I think that is the issue. Of course my solution does not show full row solution either. But that is easy to adjust using the getLastColumn function.

Comment: @Marios I thought it(open ended range) may be a issue, but when I tried, it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @TheMaster TBH I tried OP's approach before I posted my answer and it didn't work for me either when I selected  the full row.

Comment: @Marios Thank you for confirming that there's a issue

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in the desktop web app:

- Horizontal range or vertical direction of the range is not the problem
- However, When horizontal range is used, the data validation range doesn't accept a one close ended(`F3`) and a one open ended(`3`)  range (`F3:3`). If both ends are

  - open, `3:3`: The data validation is successful
  - closed, `F3:M3`: The data validation is successful
  - one side open and one side closed: `F3:3`.  This should actually calculate the lastColumn and input the range accordingly. But,The data validation input dialog drops the open end and saves the input as just `F3`.  This results in the only one cell drop down as shown in your question.
- If you are able to bypass the modal dialog of data validation and somehow force `F3:3` into the datavalidation configuration(eg through official mobile apps or scripts), the data validation is set properly.
- Consider sending feedback to Google along with this post  using Help > Help sheets improve.

Comment: I have reported the issue with your post.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to display those values horizontally so arranging them vertically in that sheet is not an option, but can you do so elsewhere?

In situations like this, I prefer to have at least one other sheet where I can list input values–let's call that sheet "INPUTS". In each column I may manually list out the values or use some formula to manually populate it (e.g. `=TRANSPOSE('Dynamic Brands'!E15:15)`). Now I can use that new range in the data validation.

Alternatively, you can build the data validation with row data, but **without the "Show dropdown list in cell"** feature. Change your criteria to a custom formula and use this formula `=ISNUMBER(MATCH('Dynamic Brands'!D15, 'Dynamic Brands'!E15:15, 0))`

Comment: Thing is, this is a dynamic dropdown. What it displays is dependent on the value selected in another cell with a dropdown. So, it's contents need to be dynamically determined using `INDIRECT`, `FILTER`, and other functions. Even if I use another sheet and arrange the contents vertically, the column to use, for a specific row, has to be determined using simple computation. Unfortunately, "List from a Range" needs a hardcoded range, it doesn't accept computed ranges which might determined using formulae. Therein, lies the main problem. I'm not sure if I'm making myself clear enough.

Comment: I like the suggested validation using the formula idea. But, it's going to make it difficult for my target audience to use the sheet.

Comment: @CodePoet Sounds like another dimension to the problem that wasn't in the question. The validation does accept a range whose values are computed, but the range address must indeed be hard coded. That means every dropdown cell would require a new data validation rule. I'd reconsider the intended design given spreadsheet limitations... or use apps script.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The actual problem is something else. I'd found a solution, but it broke down since I wasn't able to specify horizontal (open) ranges. I found my exact use case and solution here:
https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6735222?msgid=6773038

Answer (score 0):

If your column range is not dynamic select end range of your column along with row i.e with the given example instead of inserting range as `E15:15` set range as `E15:H15` that will populate all your range in dropdown

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the range needs to be dynamic. There can be any number of columns starting from column `E` in a given row. This number of columns will also vary on each row. Of course, I can probably use a huge number, say 1000 to work around the problem.